# assign names to elements of unknown size list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, console

consider I have input list contains elements 19 14 36 how to assign a name to each element say A for 1st element, B for 2nd and C for 3rd and the output is sorted list ( 14, 19, 36) but the printed list on console I want it to be (B, A,C) 
what is the  function do assignment operation in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this for an arbitrary length list would probably be something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from string import ascii_uppercase

data = [19, 14, 36]

labelled = zip(data, ascii_uppercase) # [(19, 'A'), (14, 'B'), (36, 'C')]

sorted_data = sorted(labelled, 
                     key=itemgetter(0)) # [(14, 'B'), (19, 'A'), (36, 'C')]

labels = [pair[1] for pair in sorted_data] # ['B', 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: this is the most suitable solution but i want to print only the letters not with the list elements?

Comment: That is what is in `labels`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `zip`:

```
>>> a = [19, 14, 36]
>>> b = ['A', 'B', 'C']

>>> print [b for (a,b) in sorted(zip(a,b), key=lambda x: x[0])]
['B', 'A', 'C']
```

You can experiment [here](http://repl.it/R6h)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `itemgetter` to do the trick:

```
import operator
number_arr = [19, 14, 32]
letter_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C']

zipped = zip(number_arr, letter_arr)

sorted_by_number = sorted(zipped, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

print list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), sorted_by_number))
```

Refer to python docs on [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for details